# Magento 2 after programetically cancel the order stock restored but item showing as out of stock message in reorder process

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, sales-order, frontend, reorder

I am facing a problem with resume order process.when customer click resume order I am cancelling the order programatically and creating new order with the same qty. In this process the stock is restoring immediatly after cancel step but while adding the same qty product to cart there are 2 scenarios.

1. if the ordered item > 0 stock remains (after my order) there is not problem with reorder the same item
2. If I order the item with total available stock (for example item has 4 qty and I ordered all 4 qty with my order means after my order that item qty is zero) and resume the order the stock is restoring (as per my script after cancel the order) but while adding the same qty to cart the system showing "product not available- out of stock" message.

Why this is happening I am not able to identify. I am using magento default cancel function for item cancellation. your help will save my time and get me out from this stuggle :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the issue is related with `stock` indexer? You should verify it. After cancel, mview should be updated and cron should update this information.

Comment: Hi Malis, actually the product showing "out of stock" when resume the order process only. If I order the same product with total qty from category page (without performing any reindexing process or cache clean process also) then it is adding successfully and I am able to place the order without any issue.